# HTML in SQL queries

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

```sql
--select the data to highlight using html in sql queries
select
id_c,
salary_c,
case 
when salary_c > 50000 then '<html><bgcolor=yellow><font color=red size=5><b>'||to_char(salary_c)||'<html>'
else to_char(salary_c)
END as conditionalsalary
from employees;
```

Please let me know where I did the mistake. am using oracle 11g and dbeaver client tool is.
I wanted result of conditionalsalary column high light in red color size 5 and background color yellow which are more than 50000 using html tags inside SQL query...

[image]

Comment: What is your question, exactly? The only thing "wrong" with your query is that `<bgcolor>` isn't a HTML element and the `<font>` element is an **obsolete** HTML element that you should not be using. That, and the fact that SQL should not be used to format or render values for display.

Comment: "Please let me know where i did the mistake." First, please let us know what result you were expecting so that we can understand what you consider to be a "mistake". Without knowing what you were trying to achieve it is difficult to answer the question.

Comment: You can see by the result, that the query is doing exactly what you asked for. Unless you point out what is wrong, nobody can help you.

Comment: I improved the question above. kindly check it once again...

Answer (score 2):

You’re using SQL Developer which is able to render HTML, see https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/07/using-html-to-mark-up-your-data-in-oracle-sql-developer/

Your HTML is not right, you are missing closing tags, quotes and `bgcolor` is not a valid tag as far as I can see. It probably should be:

```
select
id_c,
salary_c,
case 
when salary_c > 50000 then '<html><font color="red" size=5 style=“background-color:yellow;"><b>'||to_char(salary_c)||'</font></html>'
else to_char(salary_c)
END as conditionalsalary
from employees;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrew! But this is also returning similar results with tags in the data instead of just highlighting it.

Comment: Which SQL Developer version do you use, Rupasa? Because, values **are** nicely highlighted in my 19.4.

Comment: dbeaver tool am using it.

Comment: DBeaver doesn’t seem to have functionality to render html inside a result. If you want to do that you should just use SQL Developer which is equipped for this requirement. Otherwise you could take your results and export them to a html file then open them in a browser - obviously you might need to do some extra work to tidy things up.